# Adding a specific min width to columns in Material Table

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm adding a minimum width property to TableRow but it's not getting reflected in the application.

```
<Table className={classes.table}>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow style={{minWidth: 200}}>
                        {
                            tableData.header.map(header => {
                                return <TableCell align="center" key={header.id}>
                                    {
                                        header.title
                                    }
                                </TableCell>
                            })
                        }
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
</Table>
```

Here is the style for className.table:

```
const styles = makeStyles(theme => ({
table: {
    minWidth: 1500
},
}))
```

Earlier, I also tried adding inline style to TableCell in the same code, but it's not working. The minWidth for className.table works but it's for the entire table. A few columns that I want to increase width of remain of less width while some other columns get expanded.

There are 10 columns in all and I want to have an equal minimum width to all columns.

Comment: You have to set a min-width for cell or row?